# Restrict Searching in Hybris Solr - womens not returned in a search for mens items

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Hi Can you restrict a Hybris/Solr search so that the string 'mens' only returns mens items and not womens?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't exact answer for your question but, check blogs about solr and hybris search strategies. Rauf [blog post](https://hybrismart.com/2017/07/13/explaining-sap-hybrissolr-relevance-ranking-for-phrase-queries/) may be good start point.

If you need exact search, you can think about product classification for gender. Then boost classification then free text search.

Comment: Thanks - very useful Blog.